# POST/PUT input to Rest API

Tags: python, rest, api

I am launching REST API build in python. 
I am inputting a list as input and getting the required data.
example:

```
your.api.com/birth?name=James&date=2015-02-01&name=Robert&date=2020-01-01

from flask import request

@app.route('/birth')
def birth():
    names = request.form.getlist('name')
    dates = request.form.getlist('date')
```

As the number of inputs I have is huge, the end point URL is becoming huge. Is there any way to do the same using PUT or POST where I dump a doc in some format (say json) as my input?

Comment: Please also post the current client-side code that is sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, put the request fields in a JSON and go through the dictionary

```py
@app.route('/birth', methods=['POST'])
def birth():
    data = request.get_json()
    names = data["names"]
    # etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

When the input grows it is suggested to use a POST call rather than GET call.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/birth')
def birth():
   names = request.form.getlist('name')
   dates = request.form.getlist('date')
```

Convert `/birth` to the following

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/birth', methods=['POST'])
def birth():
   input = request.get_json() 
   # <Do the processing>
```

And in the POST call from client-side use a JSON like the following

```
{
   name: [<array of values>],
   date: [<array of values>]
}
```